# KVM what is the purpose of EXIT_QUALIFICATION

Tags: unix, virtualization, kvm

In kvm/arch/x86/vmx.c EXIT_QUALIFICATION (of type u64) is used on many places. According to my understanding it is being used for interrupt and fault handling. but not sure about this. where it is gaining values what does its specific bits mean?

Any guidance or reference for understanding the purpose and functionality of EXIT_QUALIFICATION will be great favor

**Request**

I dont know why it is voted down as i googled but no avail. I request, before vote down, to post the link for reference for explanation of concept required in my question if you think i did not put research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXIT_QUALIFICATION` refers to a field of the x86 virtual machine control structure (VMCS).  The VMCS in a single sentence controls a lot of the virtual machine state and can also be used to determine what caused the virtual machine to exit to the hypervisor.

From the Intel x86 reference manual volume 3, Section 24.9.1:

> **Exit qualification** (64 bits; 32 bits on processors that do not support Intel 64 architecture). This field contains additional
>   information about the cause of VM exits due to the following: debug
>   exceptions; page-fault exceptions; start-up IPIs (SIPIs); task
>   switches; INVEPT; INVLPG;INVVPID; LGDT; LIDT; LLDT; LTR; SGDT; SIDT;
>   SLDT; STR; VMCLEAR; VMPTRLD; VMPTRST; VMREAD; VMWRITE; VMXON;
>   control-register accesses; MOV DR; I/O instructions; and MWAIT. The
>   format of the field depends on the cause of the VM exit. See Section
>   27.2.1 for details.

Looking at places where `EXIT_QUALIFICATION` is used one finds a lot of `vmcs_readl(EXIT_QUALIFICATION)`.  This is basically reading the `EXIT_QUALFICIATION` field of the VMCS.  The VMCS has to be read via special instruction `vmread`.

Comment: what is difference with vm exit?

Comment: The first sentence of the description states "This field contains **additional information** about the cause of VM exits due to the following..."  What exactly that additional information is depends on what caused the VM exit.